# How to deploy a react project that is inside a subdirectory in the main branch to Github Pages?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

So the project repo looks like this right now
main:

- app/
- README.md
- preview.jpg

Inside of **app** directory is where all the files and folders are for my react project. I am trying to figure out how I can get the github pages to work with the sub-directory so the github-pages link displays the app. Right now all I see is a blank page.

In Package.json I have:

{
...
"homepage": "http://myUserName.github.io/name-of-the-app",
...
}

Can somebody please help?

I have tried setting deployment branch to /docs instead of /root in the gh-pages settings. That didn't do anything. I am not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. In package.json, set "homepage": "http://myUserName.github.io/name-of-the-app/app".
2. In the main index.js (or index.tsx) of your React project, add
   basename="/name-of-the-app/app" to the Router component.
3. Build your React app and rename the build folder to docs.
4. Push the changes to your GitHub repository.
5. In GitHub Pages settings, set "Source" to "main" branch and "docs"
   folder.
6. Access your app at http://myUserName.github.io/name-of-the-app/app.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try this out. I created a new repo and pushed everything there because I couldn't figure it out. But I will try this, hopefully, that will do the job.